# How do I remove last few numeric characters in Java

Tags: java

I would like to ask, How do I remove last few numeric character in Java. For examples,

```
Tiger4DK5 become Tiger4DK
Tiger10DK22 become Tiger10DK
Tiger5DK215 become Tiger5DK
```

Please advise, Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using regex :)

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("\\d*$", "");
```

Comment: It is better to use `+` instead of `*`. If there's nothing to replace, then don't replace. Also (nitpickig, yes :) `replaceFirst` is what you really need.

Comment: The desired results still have numbers in them so he wants to remove the second set of numbers.  Will this instead remove all numbers in string?

Comment: @MikeS.: No, only the ones immediately before end of string ($).